# Mariadb over VPN from a sql-IDE times out, but works with mysql CLI client, why?

Tags: mysql, openvpn

This is a situation where I don't have any clue on what's going on :

I configured an OpenVPN using a PKI, everything *seems* to work, except this:

Dbeaver and Mysql-Workbench hangs after a "succeed login" (I mean, if I set a wrong password, or a wrong allowed domain, it says it can't connect. Here, it just hangs)

What is really weird is that the mysql client works like a charm over my VPN, it's only the SQL IDEs that fails.

By the way, these IDEs have no problem to connect over internet using the public IPv4.

Any idea of what I could do to :

1) Investigate the problem (first VPN I set up... I might have missed something or is there some settings that could obviously lead to this behaviour I'm not aware)

2) Solve the problem

?

[EDIT] : For the tests, I set an empty iptables rule set and disabled fail2ban (and everything else that could cause firewall problems) :

```
2018-12-17 11:46:24 root /etc/openvpn/ #>iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

routes :

```
2018-12-17 11:49:17 root /etc/openvpn/ #>ip route                                                              
default via 10.16.84.150 dev ens2 proto dhcp src 10.16.84.151 metric 1024 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1 
10.16.84.150 dev ens2 proto dhcp scope link src 10.16.84.151 metric 1024 
10.16.84.150/31 dev ens2 proto kernel scope link src 10.16.84.151
```

These are the ones set by openVPN :

```
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
```

**[EDIT 2]**

I tried some wireshark on the server and my computer to see what's going on here the result afeter a "test the connectio" with dbeaver :

on **Client**

```
    tshark -i tun0
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
tshark: Lua: Error during loading:
 /usr/share/wireshark/init.lua:32: dofile has been disabled due to running Wireshark as superuser. See https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges for help in running Wireshark as an unprivileged user.
Capturing on 'tun0'
    1 0.000000000     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     TCP 60 47148 → 3306 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=999443647 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2 0.049160978     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 60 3306 → 47148 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3444840768 TSecr=999443647 WS=128
    3 0.049178626     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     TCP 52 47148 → 3306 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=999443696 TSecr=3444840768
    4 0.084592971     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 145 Server Greeting proto=10 version=5.5.5-10.1.37-MariaDB
    5 0.084630234     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     TCP 52 47148 → 3306 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=94 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=999443731 TSecr=3444840803
    6 0.085223320     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 282 Login Request user=root db=fbpl_dataset
    7 0.128639717     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 52 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=231 Win=30080 Len=0 TSval=3444840848 TSecr=999443732
    8 0.128899853     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 63 Response OK
    9 0.129036157     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 162 Request Query
   10 0.166717953     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 422 Response
   11 0.167034485     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 168 Request Query
   12 0.201992947     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 63 Response OK
   13 0.202300657     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 100 Request Query
   14 0.244425110     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 63 Response OK
   15 0.244723180     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 73 Request Query
   16 0.282299897     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 63 Response OK
   17 0.282750321     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 63 Request Query
   18 0.324337397     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 63 Response OK
   19 0.325020740     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 88 Request Query
   20 0.363417862     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 131 Response
   21 0.380069274     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 69 Request Query
   22 0.426607694     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 1288 Response
   23 0.427432886     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 69 Request Query
   24 0.464371877     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1037 [TCP Previous segment not captured] 3306 → 47148 [PSH, ACK] Seq=3180 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=985 TSval=3444841181 TSecr=999444074 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   25 0.464403500     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     TCP 64 [TCP Window Update] 47148 → 3306 [ACK] Seq=607 Ack=1834 Win=35712 Len=0 TSval=999444111 TSecr=3444841142 SLE=3180 SRE=4165
   26 0.648240382     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 47946 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125070191 TSecr=0 WS=128
   27 15.154852195 fe80::2b5f:797f:89b6:2163 → ff02::2      ICMPv6 48 Router Solicitation
   28 17.460851851     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 47970 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125087000 TSecr=0 WS=128
   29 18.461720007     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47970 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125088001 TSecr=0 WS=128
   30 20.488217123     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47970 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125090027 TSecr=0 WS=128
   31 24.541683888     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47970 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125094080 TSecr=0 WS=128
   32 32.648223719     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47970 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125102185 TSecr=0 WS=128
   33 76.255359872     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   34 76.594972111 fe80::2b5f:797f:89b6:2163 → ff02::2      ICMPv6 48 Router Solicitation
   35 77.255689579     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   36 78.256235262     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   37 79.256582538     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   38 81.468184482     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 47992 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125150997 TSecr=0 WS=128
   39 82.488202760     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47992 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125152016 TSecr=0 WS=128
   40 84.701712530     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47992 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125154230 TSecr=0 WS=128
   41 88.754872248     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47992 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125158282 TSecr=0 WS=128
   42 96.861639556     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47992 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125166388 TSecr=0 WS=128
   43 196.255874050     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   44 197.257068532     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   45 198.258297209     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   46 199.258728979     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   47 204.595034169 fe80::2b5f:797f:89b6:2163 → ff02::2      ICMPv6 48 Router Solicitation
   48 209.531734561     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 48004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125279045 TSecr=0 WS=128
   49 210.541697498     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 48004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125280055 TSecr=0 WS=128
   50 212.701695301     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 48004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125282215 TSecr=0 WS=128
   51 216.755028817     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 48004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125286268 TSecr=0 WS=128
   52 224.861647492     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 48004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125294374 TSecr=0 WS=128
   53 316.256315832     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   54 317.257280083     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   55 318.258064000     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   56 319.258529228     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
```

On **Server** :

```
    tshark
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
tshark: Lua: Error during loading:
 /usr/share/wireshark/init.lua:32: dofile has been disabled due to running Wireshark as superuser. See https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges for help in running Wireshark as an unprivileged user.
Capturing on 'tun0'
    1 0.000000000     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     TCP 60 47148 → 3306 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=999443647 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2 0.000053386     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 60 3306 → 47148 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3444840768 TSecr=999443647 WS=128
    3 0.034842750     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     TCP 52 47148 → 3306 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=999443696 TSecr=3444840768
    4 0.035454228     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 145 Server Greeting proto=10 version=5.5.5-10.1.37-MariaDB
    5 0.074777548     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     TCP 52 47148 → 3306 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=94 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=999443731 TSecr=3444840803
    6 0.079692859     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 282 Login Request user=root db=fbpl_dataset
    7 0.079706973     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 52 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=231 Win=30080 Len=0 TSval=3444840848 TSecr=999443732
    8 0.079907092     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 63 Response OK
    9 0.114271069     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 162 Request Query
   10 0.116406475     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 422 Response
   11 0.153284108     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 168 Request Query
   12 0.153484577     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 63 Response OK
   13 0.194794969     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 100 Request Query
   14 0.195012071     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 63 Response OK
   15 0.232990157     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 73 Request Query
   16 0.233240592     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 63 Response OK
   17 0.274414074     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 63 Request Query
   18 0.274611706     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 63 Response OK
   19 0.313793459     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 88 Request Query
   20 0.314036139     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 131 Response
   21 0.373724977     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 69 Request Query
   22 0.374313462     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 1288 Response
   23 0.412753261     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     MySQL 69 Request Query
   24 0.413313088     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 1398 Response
   25 0.413332858     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 1037 ResponseResponse
   26 0.453471537     10.8.0.6 → 10.8.0.1     TCP 64 [TCP Window Update] 47148 → 3306 [ACK] Seq=607 Ack=1834 Win=35712 Len=0 TSval=999444111 TSecr=3444841142 SLE=3180 SRE=4165
   27 0.471486585     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3444841239 TSecr=999444111
   28 0.653949113     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 47946 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125070191 TSecr=0 WS=128
   29 0.738141927     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3444841506 TSecr=999444111
   30 1.244791421     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3444842013 TSecr=999444111
   31 1.564860995     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     MySQL 1398 Response
   32 2.231524259     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3444842999 TSecr=999444111
   33 4.338152670     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3444845106 TSecr=999444111
   34 8.391500815     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3444849159 TSecr=999444111
   35 16.284812186     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3444857053 TSecr=999444111
   36 17.453808438     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 47970 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125087000 TSecr=0 WS=128
   37 18.442690460     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47970 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125088001 TSecr=0 WS=128
   38 20.473716795     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47970 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125090027 TSecr=0 WS=128
   39 24.513887900     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47970 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125094080 TSecr=0 WS=128
   40 32.284844755     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3444873053 TSecr=999444111
   41 32.634593171     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47970 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125102185 TSecr=0 WS=128
   42 64.711502663     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3444905479 TSecr=999444111
   43 76.239261484     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   44 77.239606533     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   45 78.248116041     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   46 79.240570533     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   47 81.458991045     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 47992 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125150997 TSecr=0 WS=128
   48 82.473039673     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47992 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125152016 TSecr=0 WS=128
   49 84.679898494     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47992 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125154230 TSecr=0 WS=128
   50 88.739155711     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47992 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125158282 TSecr=0 WS=128
   51 96.840751788     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 47992 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125166388 TSecr=0 WS=128
   52 124.444841498     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47008 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=235 Len=1346 TSval=3444965213 TSecr=998700357
   53 127.858151192     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3444968626 TSecr=999444111
   54 196.234990777     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   55 197.236207702     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   56 198.236346847     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   57 199.235242415     10.8.0.6 → 239.255.255.250 SSDP 193 M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 
   58 209.476349902     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 48004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125279045 TSecr=0 WS=128
   59 210.509956728     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 48004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125280055 TSecr=0 WS=128
   60 212.674468626     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 48004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125282215 TSecr=0 WS=128
   61 216.716790577     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 48004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125286268 TSecr=0 WS=128
   62 224.828569147     10.8.0.6 → 138.201.81.199 TCP 60 [TCP Retransmission] 48004 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1358 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2125294374 TSecr=0 WS=128
   63 260.978128154     10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.6     TCP 1398 [TCP Retransmission] 3306 → 47148 [ACK] Seq=1834 Ack=607 Win=30080 Len=1346 TSval=3445101746 TSecr=999444111
```

**[Edit 3]**
 It seems like it's acually a network problem : with dbeaver, a tcp window  update occurs. Then, my pc doesn't receive anypacket from the connection. I also wiresharked the physical link and indeed, no further udp packet are received, so heavily suspect a MTU problem. I tested the VPN over TCP, and it works.

Comment: It's clearly related to your IDEs. You can establish a connection to the mysql server and authenticate so you can forget about network configurations. My approach would be checking the IDEs' configuration to see if there's anything causing trouble there.

Comment: That's what I though first, but how do you explain the IDEs work using public IPv4 (and that it's two different IDE's having the same problem, though they both use the java connector) ?

Comment: Well, tried with GSQL and works too so it maybe more probable than what I though

Comment: @sysfiend I added some wireshark trace. Seems like an ACK is not received by the server, since it keeps sending again the same packet

Comment: just for the shake of testing, start a `nc -l 60` on the server and do `nc server_ip 60` from the client. Looks like, as you mentioned, the problem is in the network, but I can't find an explanation on why (with no firewall rules) you can't connect.

Comment: Btw, check wheter firewalld is running or not and disable it if so. If you are running on Centos, disable selinux.